# Non Deterministic issues with Persisted Columns whilst working with datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

As I've spent two hours trying to fix this and couldn't find the answer on SO, I've decided to add a new question.  In hindsight, the answer can be answered on SO, but only if you're looking for it in the right place.

PROBLEM:
Whilst trying to persist a calculated column (which in my case includes `cast('2013-09-30 23:59:59' as datetime)` in SQL Server I get an error advising that it cannot be persisted as it is `non-deterministic`.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:
Use `CONVERT` rather than `CAST` and specify a `style`, example `convert(datetime,'2013-09-30 23:59:59',120)`.  In this example, `120` is the style and refers to the YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS format.

CAVEAT:
I have seen some posts suggesting that some styles can be non-deterministic, so check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx for the full run down on styles.

Comment: All styles smaller than 100 are non-deterministic because of lack of century (13 can be 2013 or 1913 based on cutoff setting). Also styles 106,107,109,113 because of use of names for months which are different based on language.